# array_marge is very slow

Tags: php, merge, explode

My array

```
$AppDocumentList=[["TAGS"=>"a&b^c&d"],["TAGS"=>"d^b&c"],["TAGS"=>"a^d&e"],["TAGS"=>"33^de^ee3"]]
```

$AppDocumentList has 105,000 record

My code

```
$Tag=array();
foreach($AppDocumentList as $D){
    //split with &
    $x=explode('&',$D["APP_DOC_TAGS"]);

    foreach($x as $R){
        //split with ^ and merge 
        $Tag=array_merge($Tag,explode('^',$R));
    }

}
```

This code split Tag with `^` and `&`  then merge to old value
But this code is very slow and it takes ten minutes to complete.
Is there a way to reduce this time?

[Demo](https://ideone.com/S01n2t)

Comment: What is the source of the data?  how often does it change? If you can't change how it is stored/sent to you, then process it once and store the results.